# Change mail from header in sendmail

Tags: email, dns, sendmail, spf

We have two separate RTs (request trackers) configured on one server. They both are configured to send the emails through sendmail. We are trying to configure now SPF and DMARC records for these DNS names. What we achieved for now is that SPF passes but DMARC fails. If I understood correctly the reason for DMARC fail is that From header of the email is set to support@dns.name.rt1 while envelope From header is set to apache@server.dns.name. "server.dns.name" is added in the SPF record as the trusted one, so SPF passes.

Is there an option in sendmail to set envelope From header the same as From? In other words we need it to be set dinamically to support@dns.name.rt1 or sales@dns.name.rt2.

What I have currently found is using masquerade feature, but if I understood correctly only one DNS can be used there.

Or is there an option for DMARC to pass with the current difference in the domains in From headers?